# How can I assign an array to pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, addressof

The following code:

```
main(){
uint8_t id = 1;
uint8_t str[] = "shutdown 1";
uint8_t* (rcm)[];

rcm = &str; //line 83
```

Returns the warning in line 83:

```
invalid lvalue in assignment
```

Anyone know how can I solve that? I'm stucked on this for hours...

Comment: You can't assign an array to a pointer. But you can assign a pointer to a pointer. Like `uint8_t ptr = str;`

Comment: As for the problem for your current code, you declare `rcm` to be an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. The type of `&str` is `uint8_t (*)[11]` (and yes, the size is part of the type).

Comment: If you want `str` to be an array of characters, define `str` as `char str[] = "shutdown 1";`, you can access a pointer to the first element of the array by just accessing `str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array declared like

```
uint8_t str[] = "shutdown 1";
```

then a pointer to the first element of the array will look like

```
uint8_t *rcm = str;
```

If you want to declare a pointer that will point to the whole array as a single object then you can write

```
uint8_t ( *rcm )[11] = &str;
```

As for this record

```
uint8_t* (rcm)[];
```

then it is not a declaration of a pointer. It is a declaration of an array with unknown size and with the element type `uint8_t *`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I missed the pointer size, anyway I'm still stucked on that. I'll post the entire code regarding the same issue.